# Using LLVM/Clang as a cross compiler

Tags: clang, llvm

I'm trying to understand a how to use LLVM/clang as a cross compiler. There are some aspects of the process that are not immediately clear.

The LLVM docs often mention that clang is 'natively a cross compiler'. However, is this only true if it was built to be a cross compiler in the first place?

If I want to build for the target `armv7a-linux-eabihf` for example, do I have to build LLVM/clang with some option that includes that target in a list of possible targets?

Would this then build the required runtime libraries as well?

Answer (score 2):

I didn't try cross-compiling to ARM, the answer below is based on my experience cross-compiling to Windows (x86) with various MinGW flavors.

---

> The LLVM docs often mention that clang is 'natively a cross compiler'. However, is this only true if it was built to be a cross compiler in the first place?

As far as I know, any (?) Clang binary can compile for any supported platform; you don't need different binaries for different platforms. (Unlike GCC, for example.)

What you do need are various libraries for the target platform.

The minimal necessary flags are `--target=?? --sysroot=??`, where "target" is probably `armv7a-linux-eabihf` (confirm this by running `clang --version` on the target platform), and "sysroot" is the root directory (`/`) copied from the target OS. In theory only libraries and headers are necessary, but it's easier to copy everything.

Other useful flags are listed below. Some of them might have default values provided by your Clang's binary.

- `-fuse-ld=lld` (or `-fuse-ld=lld-$VERSION`) to use Clang's own linker.
- `-stdlib=libstdc++` or `-stdlib=libc++` to select C++ standard library.
- I also believe that using atomics on libstdc++ needs `-femulated-tls` and on libc++ it needs `-fno-emulated-tls`. That's the case for Windows x86, unsure about ARM.
- If the target OS doesn't have libgcc, I believe you also need `-rtlib=compiler-rt -unwindlib=libunwind -resource-dir=$YOUR_SYSROOT/lib/clang/$CLANG_VERSION`, and otherwise you want `-rtlib=libgcc`.

If something doesn't work, add the `-v` flag and compare the output between the cross-compiler and Clang running directly on the target platform. You might need to add some extra flags.

Answer (score -1):

Clang is inherently a cross compiler because of its design: When you compile clang, you have to decide which targets to support, and there's nothing special about the target for the platform clang runs on. That there's nothing special about that is what makes clang a cross compiler.

And no, it won't build libraries. It's a compiler, it's not the other things you need.

Comment: When you build LLVM/clang from source, you can also optionally build runtime libraries like `compiler-rt`. I was wondering if they also support the targets LLVM/clang is built for.

Comment: Compiler-rt supports some of LLVM's targets, far from all, and may not be enough for you even if it does support the platform you care about. (Also, for your future questions, please name the subject clearly. If you're asking about compiler-rt, for example, mention that by name instead of just clang.)