# How to cross-compile to linux(Ubuntu) in windows using llvm and cmake

Tags: c++, clang, cross-compiling

I want to cross compile for Linux using llvm in windows without the use of WSL and docker.

Comment: Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72254698/2752075). That's for a different platform, you need to substitute `--target=??` for whatever target `clang++ --version` returns on your Linux.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat -- well placed link -- works every time. Not sure, but your answer and the other question looks like a strong dupe candidate.